# When using qlSmileSectionFromSabrVolSurface in Quantlibxl, why the Option Time for input cannot be less than 1?

Tags: quantlib

I constructed a SabrVolSurface in Quantlibxl. Then I wanted to obtain a volatility smile from the surface using qlSmileSectionFromSabrVolSurface. The problem is that the time input is the year-fraction unit, when I input a number which is 0~1, for example 0.4, it shows error: "negative time(-0.594) given".

I went back to the C++ code in Quantlib and found out that qlSmileSectionFromSabrVolSurface calls a function BlackVolSurface::smileSection(Time t, bool extrapolate), and it by default sets the extrapolation as true in qlSmileSectionFromSabrVolSurface. Inside BlackVolSurface::smileSection, it first checks the range of the time, which is

```
 void TermStructure::checkRange(Time t,
                                    bool extrapolate) const {
         QL_REQUIRE(t >= 0.0,
                    "negative time (" << t << ") given");
         QL_REQUIRE(extrapolate || allowsExtrapolation()
                    || t <= maxTime() || close_enough(t, maxTime()),
                    "time (" << t << ") is past max curve time ("
                             << maxTime() << ")");
     }
```

I have three main questions that I cannot solve:

1. why my input is larger than 0 but the range check says negative time.
2. when I input larger than max interpolating time, it says "it passed max curve time", as by default it sets extrapolation as true?
3. When I input a time that works, the volatilities it gives are not so aligned with the ones I obtained from qlVolatilitySpreads, where the latter ones are much more close to the actual points.

Really appreciate for the answers